# Angular i18n == multiple copies of the same app?

Tags: angular, internationalization

I'm new to the i18n in Angular. (And I'm using Angular 5.1.0.)

I decided to use the built-in i18n (and not ngx-translate or other), because I think that will be more supported in the future.

I started to read the official documentation and other articles, but there is one thing I don't get:

Let's say that I have to use 3 different languages, then... I have to build my application 3 times? So basically that means, that I have 3 copies of the same application, and switching between languages is actually loading the other copy of the app?

I know, that I can't change language in runtime, but having multiple copies of the same app doesn't feel right. I hope I'm wrong. Or is there any other solution to this?

Comment: No, you do not need to build three times. You can provide translation as options before   platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, options). Then you have to reload pages when changing languages.

Comment: @Yong This depends on how you deploy your App I guess. E.g. if AOT is used and the dist folder is just put on a server without any ng serve, then you need to actually build it for every language.